# How to deserialize an api response given dynamic column list? C# .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, json, http, asp.net-core

Say you have an endpoint that returns a JSON response with a dynamic list of indexed columns, in the following format:

```
"columnNames": [
  "date",
  "value",
  "someOtherValue"
],
"data": [
  [
    "2019-05-29",
    1.23,
    2.34
  ],
  [
    "2019-05-28",
    0.20,
    1.34
  ],
  [
    "2019-05-27,
    2.99,
    1.94
  ]
]
```

What would be the most optimal way to deserialize such a response? I could try mapping it to some class which would contain both the columnNames and the data and afterwards just map it out, more or less like this (pseudo code):

```
var apiResponseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiResponse>();
foreach(var responseData in apiResponseContent.data) {
  var model = new Model();
  model.date = responseData[apiResponseContent.columnNames.First(v => v == "date").index]
  ..
}
```

But this seems to be such typical scenario, that there should be a more efficient alternative that is not prone to break if the endpoint response changes. Of course I could use reflection and create an extension method to automatically map out the columns to classes but it seems odd for me to do it.

Comment: have u looked a EF Core ?

Comment: I am not using EF Core, I am using Mongo as a persistent data store. What does one have to do with the other?

Comment: Not sure how we can help without you explaining the structure a bit more. How does one response differ to another for example? What assumptions can we make?

Comment: @PiotrJerzyMamenas your post did not mention Mongo

Comment: Also, this is not well formatted JSON.

Comment: @saj one doesn't have anything to do with the other so why would it? And it's also only a part of a json...

Comment: @PiotrJerzyMamenas if you mean anything to do with Mongo, I already said you didn't mention it earlier, i'm not sure what your alluding to or how it helps with your question either.

Comment: @saj Well I also didn't mention I use jwt tokens for authorization but that's because this post has zero to do with jwt tokens or authorization..... Similarly it has zero to do with datastores... This question is about a http response parsing not about object relational mappers or datastores, EF Core or Mongo could COMPLETELY not exist here and I could just be saving this to a text file on the disc or not saving it at all and just output it to console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a peculiar format, especially with the data arrays containing varying types. However, you could use a simple class like this:

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ColumnNames { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<List<object>> Data { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to map this object to another set of object, you could use a generic function that uses reflection, for example:

```
public List<T> MapTo<T>(ApiResponse source) 
    where T : new()
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    foreach (var datum in source.Data)
    {
        var t = new T();

        for(var colIndex = 0; colIndex < source.ColumnNames.Count; colIndex++)
        {
            var property = properties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(source.ColumnNames[colIndex], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (property != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(t, Convert.ChangeType(datum[colIndex], property.PropertyType));
            }
        }
        yield return t;
    }
}
```

And your final code could look something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public double SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}


var apiResponseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiResponse>();
var actualData = MapTo<Foo>(apiResponseContent);
```

Comment: Yeah that's the approach I meant with reflection. Thanks, let's see if other people have other ideas.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't another way of doing this, there is no built in deserialiser, so you either need to use specific code or use reflection to be able to handle any type.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go for the reflection solution but slightly adjusted. I am using AutoMapper on the project so to maintain architectural consistency I wrote a ValueResolver that essentially wraps around your approach, just with a few adjustments:

```
public class VariableColumnConverter : ITypeConverter<ApiResponse, List<AssetPrice>>
{
    public List<AssetPrice> Convert(ApiResponse source, List<AssetPrice> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var properties = typeof(AssetPrice).GetProperties();
        destination = new List<AssetPrice>();

        foreach (var dataItem in source.data)
        {
            var price = new AssetPrice();

            foreach (var column in source.columnNames.Select((value, i) => (value, i)))
            {
                var property = properties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(column.value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

                if (property != null)
                {
                    property.SetValue(price, System.Convert.ChangeType(dataItem[column.i], property.PropertyType));
                }
            }
            destination.Add(price);
        }

        return destination;
    }
}
```

Thanks @DavidG, I removed the generic since I only have one endpoint like that. I will tag your answer as correct since my end approach is a little opinionated and the root uses your approach.

Regardless, there are some small issues with your code which make it not compile, `Root` would actually be `ApiResponse`, also since IEnumerable does not contain a definition of indexation methods, you cannot use the [] operator. Would be great if you could please adjust it. Also, I would personally suggest using Decimal type for floating point numbers.